# Drawing a minimap in SFML/C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I understand that I can already create a minimap by modifying a view object, as outlined [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-view.php), but what I want instead is a small rectangle that will have a box or an arrow representing the player, and other colored boxes that represent enemies or various objects. Is there a better way to do this than simply create a Minimap object that calculates where each enemy is and translates that into a representational object (box, arrow.. etc) that then gets drawn to the screen?

This is a general question more than anything, so I'm not really expecting sample code, even though it would be much appreciated. I'm outlining a minimap class now and I'll upload it here soon.

Here is what I'm doing in my draw loop:

```
minimap.setCenter(player.getPosition());
minimap.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.25f, 0.25f)); 
//Bottom right corner of screen

window.setView(minimap);

window.draw(player);

window.setView(view); //Return to default view
```

With a call to `minimap.zoom(10);` when the view is initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I tried this:

```
window.setView(minimap);

sf::CircleShape object;
object.setRadius(200);
object.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
object.setPosition(player.getPosition());
window.draw(object);


object.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
for (auto& e : enemies)
{
    object.setPosition(e->getPosition());
    window.draw(object);
}

window.setView(view);
```

And that worked. Obviously it would benefit from being in its own class, so that the circle didn't have to be recreated each loop etc..

If there's a better way to do this, be sure to mention it.

Here's a screenshot of the Minimap (Bottom Right):
[image: screenshot]